# Mockito and matching varargs properly with overloaded methods with Spring Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, redis, mockito

I have following method in my service.

```
private final ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplate;
public Mono<Boolean> deleteObject(String... keys) {
    return reactiveRedisTemplate.delete(keys).map(c -> c > 0);
}
```

ReactiveRedisTemplate has two internal implementations for delete with different signatures.

```
@SafeVarargs
public final Mono<Long> delete(K... keys) {
    Assert.notNull(keys, "Keys must not be null!");
    Assert.notEmpty(keys, "Keys must not be empty!");
    Assert.noNullElements(keys, "Keys must not contain null elements!");
    if (keys.length == 1) {
    ...


public Mono<Long> delete(Publisher<K> keys) {
    Assert.notNull(keys, "Keys must not be null!");
    return this.doCreateFlux((connection) -> {
```

Now, when I have the following

```
var key = "key";
when(reactiveRedisTemplate.delete(key)).thenReturn(Mono.just(1L));
StepVerifier.create(service.removeObject(key))
            .expectNextMatches(c -> c)
            .verifyComplete();
verify(this.reactiveRedisTemplate, times(1)).delete(key);
```

I'm getting error NullPointerException, so it looks like the varargs doesn't match. With ArgumentMatcher, following is received:

```
when(reactiveRedisTemplate.delete(ArgumentMatchers.<String>any())).thenReturn(Mono.just(1L));
=> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys must not contain null elements!

when(reactiveRedisTemplate.delete(eq(new String[] { key }))).thenReturn(Mono.just(1L));
=> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys must not be null!

when(reactiveRedisTemplate.delete(anyString())).thenReturn(Mono.just(1L));
=> java.lang.NullPointerException (doesn't seem to match)
```

lastly a custom matcher:

```
public class StringVarargsMatcher implements VarargMatcher, ArgumentMatcher<String[]> {
    private String[] expectedValues;

    public StringVarargsMatcher(String... expectedValues) {
        Arrays.sort(expectedValues);
        this.expectedValues = expectedValues;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String[] strings) {
        Arrays.sort(strings);
        return Arrays.equals(strings, expectedValues);
    }
}
when(reactiveRedisTemplate.delete(argThat(new StringVarargsMatcher(key)))).thenReturn(Mono.just(1L));
=> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys must not be null!
```

Is there any way to overcome this so I could mock delete from ReactiveRedisTemplate and get a unit test done here?

Comment: Are you using an inline mock maker?

Comment: No, I'm not using inline mock maker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mocking `public final Mono<Long> delete(K... keys)` as it is a final method and you are not using inline mock maker (as discussed in comments).

As a consequence, real method is called.

ArgumentMatcher factory methods, such as `any()`

- register a metcher in Mockitos internal state
- return null

Combine that with a real method being called - you get errors on assertions made by the real method.

See: [Mocking final types, enums and final methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39)